# What is the difference between ⊕ and + here?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, addition

```
A = A + S[0];
B = B + S[1];

for i = 1 to r do
    A = ((A ⊕ B) <<< B) + S[2i];
    B = ((B ⊕ A) <<< A) + S[2i + 1];
```

It's the [RC5 encryption algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5), what is the difference between ⊕ and + here?

Answer (score 0):

`+` is addition; `⊕` is bitwise XOR.

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5#Encryption for a notation using `^` (C-style XOR).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Alternative_symbols for an explanation of the symbol.

Comment: @RicardodaRochaVitor What, in RC5? How so?

Comment: RC5 is a very simple algorithm to crypt.
As you can see,
`A = A + S[0];
B = B + S[1];

for i = 1 to r do
    A = ((A ⊕ B) <<< B) + S[2i];
    B = ((B ⊕ A) <<< A) + S[2i + 1];` are logic operation

Answer (score 0):

```
A = A OR S[0]; 
B = B OR S[1]; 

for i = 1 to r do 
A = ((A XOR B) <<< B) OR S[2i]; 
B = ((B XOR A) <<< A) OR S[2i OR 1];
```

`<<<` means a bitwise operation